# Execute SELECT queries from a SELECT result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to get users' id from a table named `User` and get datas in others table for each user id.

I use PDO and MySQL in php, AND :

1. I can't make this task in one query because there is too many datas that I must make unbuffered queries.
2. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to get datas for each user
   id without making queries in a loop

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: For example :

There is datas in tables GpsPosition and PizzaEaten
You want for each user get his GpsPosition and PizzaEaten
But there is too many datas that you CAN'T do it in one query 
How to do it without looping in all users of the table User to get all the data you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to decompose your data, include other datas from other tables to `User`, it is improve your perofrmance

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it, it's just a join

```
SELECT ot.data1, ot.data2, ot.data3, ...
FROM Users u, other_table ot
WHERE u.id = ot.id_user
AND u.id = [your id]
```

Comment: I can't make a join query because my query recover too many datas (over 40GB) that's why I wanted to find a solution ... I would do it if I could ! :)